# Hosting Automated Browser Tests

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, browser-testing

I am aiming to use automated testing to ensure that specific pages of a website are loading, rather than look/feel of UI elements or performance testing.

I have set up a number of selenium scripts, using ruby, which are executable locally for each test. My aim is to host that somewhere and add some form of text/email notification if one of the tests fail.

What is the best way to go about this? 
Presumably some sort of linux server setup with selenium running headless from it could work. Would it be best to run this from some sort of rails or sinatra app with scheduling?

Comment: how you run the tests?

Comment: at the moment, just loading the individual ruby test files in the command line locally. That is more to ensure they work than anything else.

Comment: Better use Jenkins and run test files a Jenkins job. Add some plugins to send you notifications.